# How long does it take for updated static files to start being served?

Tags: google-app-engine

I’ve just updated most of my static files but it seems that the old versions of those files are still being served. How long does it usually take for the new versions to be served? Is there any ways to speed that up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking on production server?
In my project, usually they are affected immediately. Sometime due to the caching framework ,it keeps old static file served. I'm using Django-nonrel.
If you are using Google Chrome, you can you `Inspect Element` to see if it has an `cache-control` header or not.
Also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642432/google-app-engine-how-to-disable-cache-on-static-files-or-make-cache-smart) will help you to change `default_expiration` on app engine.
Maybe it gives you some clues

Answer (score 2):

I've found that it's usually immediate but sometimes takes about 15 minutes or so. For css/js many people append a build # to the filenames to break the cache.