# GCP App Engine - How to serve newest files

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm using GCP App Engine with auto scaling.

If I deploy a new version of the app code (Python 3 Flask app) with a simple change for control and test purposes, lets say I add a comment to one of the .js files I am not seeing that change to the file in the browser after it has been deployed.

I have 100% of traffic being served by the new version of the app. When I look at the source code for the version I can see the comment in there, but when I clear my browser cache and visit the page I only ever get the old version of the page (without the comment in the .js).

I have tried using the --promote and --no-cache values in the app deploy command, but no use. I have added:

```
default_expiration: "0d 0h 0m 0s"
```

To the app.yaml

I have also turned on object versioning of the storage account which app engine uses to try to ensure that only a single version of the file is available to be served - still no use.

The command I'm using to deploy is:

```
run: "gcloud app deploy app.yaml --quiet --promote --no-cache"
```

I can't understand why it should be so difficult to simply deploy a new version of the app and have the app engine serve the latest files; I must be doing something wrong but cannot see what.

Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google App Engine: How to disable cache on 'static' files, or make cache smart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642432/google-app-engine-how-to-disable-cache-on-static-files-or-make-cache-smart)

Comment: @newname Thanks I have implemented everything I could find there and in other posts, including versioning the storage account objects. I see no-cache in the request and response headers. 

Even in private and incognito tabs it still does not show the version of the .js which it shows as the source in the app engine console.
 
But still, I cannot get it to serve the updated files. It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are cached (even if for a short while and sometimes it takes time to clear it).

The trick is to make the urls (for the static files) unique for each deployment. This way, the browser is loading a 'distinct' url after each deployment. For example, you could append the environment variable, `CURRENT_VERSION_ID` to the url for all static elements. This means having something like (assuming Python/Jinja2)

```
src="/static/js/my_js_file.js?{{CURRENT_VERSION_ID}}"
```

`os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']` changes for each deployment. There's a possibility this attribute is not available in newer runtimes. If so, just dump the environment variables and look for an attribute that is always present but the value changes (e.g. `GAE_INSTANCE`).

You could also just generate a random number each time your App is deployed and use that instead i.e.

```
src="/static/js/my_js_file.js?{{RANDOM_NUMBER}}"
```

Comment: I tried this ysing the GAE_VERSION env var. It works too!

In my case, its going to be quite a bit of work to retrofit this behaviour into a large project. 

Additionally, I'm actually not clear on HOW this works. I appreciate that the version is being passed in as a parameter or argument in the URL, but the static file itself is not being renamed so how does app engine know how to serve that version? Is this a documented feature? I could totally get this if the static file were being renamed to incorporate a unique/incrementing value, but its not. Any insight on how ths works?

Comment: Make sure ```GAE_VERSION``` changes with each deploy. I was under the impression the variable referred to the version of ```gcloud CLI``` which is currently being run in which case it shouldn't change (but I could be wrong). Regarding your second question - this is a know tactic for cache bursting i.e. just append a query parameter with a different value and browsers will see the url as being unique and will reload it. I know for a fact this also works with Twitter (you tweet a url with an image, make a slight change to the image and twee it it again; Twitter still still shows the old url)

Comment: GAE_VERSION changes between deployments and as far as I can see will work very well for me. Refactoring the codebase is not going to be as bad as I thought and experimentation seems to show that its a rock solid cache-buster fix. Fantastic technique! Thank you so much for sharing it.