# Google App Engine doesn't update Angular built files

Tags: .net, angular, google-app-engine, github-actions, cicd

Ok, as the title states, I have a .net angular app that I deployed to Google's App Engine.

My problem is that when I run my workflow I create the static files that I add to my wwwroot folder but because they have always the same names generated it results to google saying that there is no need to update them.

Is there a way to force this folder to always update?

Any help or suggestions would be highly appriciated as I am new to CI/CD and I am walking in the dark with everything related to the .net/angular deployment to the App Engine as this is my first try.

```
name: Build and Deploy to Google App Engine
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js for Angular
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '18'

      - name: Install Angular dependencies and build
        run: |
          cd Client
          npm install
          npm run build

      - name: Move files from wwwroot/browser to wwwroot
        run: |
          cd API/wwwroot
          mv browser/* .
          rmdir browser
      
      - name: Update file timestamps <- Here ChatGPT suggested to update the timestamp of the files but it didn't work...
        run: |
          cd API/wwwroot
          find . -exec touch {} +

      - name: Set up .NET Framework
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.0'

      - name: Build .NET Application
        run: |
          dotnet restore
          dotnet build
          dotnet publish

      - name: Set up Google Cloud SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0.2.0
        with:
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
          project_id: PROJECT_ID

      - name: Deploy to Google App Engine
        run: |
          gcloud app deploy API/app.yaml
```

Comment: Don't know about ```.net``` with GAE but maybe you have a similar issue with other runtimes on GAE where updated static content takes awhile to showup (App shows old content for awhile). See if this [StackOverflow Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73599640/gcp-app-engine-how-to-serve-newest-files/73600523#73600523) helps