# Google App Engine - SiteMap Creation for a social network

Tags: google-app-engine, sitemap

I am creating a social tool - I want to allow search engines to pick up "public" user profiles - like twitter and face-book.

I have seen all the protocol info at http://www.sitemaps.org and i understand this and how to build such a file - along with an index if i exceed the 50K limit.

Where i am struggling is the concept of how i make this run.

The site map for my general site pages is simple i can use a tool to create the file - or a script - host the file - submit the file and done.

What i then need is a script that will create the site-maps of user profiles. I assume this would be something like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.socialsite.com/profile/spidee</loc>
      <lastmod>2010-5-12</lastmod>
      <changefreq>???</changefreq>
      <priority>???</priority>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.socialsite.com/profile/webbsterisback</loc>
      <lastmod>2010-5-12</lastmod>
      <changefreq>???</changefreq>
      <priority>???</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

Ive added some ??? as i don't know how i should set these settings for my profiles based on the following:-

When a new profile is created it must be added to a site-map. If the profile is changed or if "certain" properties are changed - then i don't know if i update the entry in the map - or do something else? (updating would be a nightmare!)

Some users may change their profile. In terms of relevance to the search engine the only way a google or yahoo search will find the users (for my requirement) profile would be for example by means of [user name] and [location] so once the entry for the profile has been added to the map file the only reason to have the search-bot re-index the profile would be if the user changed their user-name - which they cant. or their location - and or set their settings so that their profile would be "hidden" from search engines.

I assume my map creation will need to be dynamic. From what i have said above i would imagine that creating a new profile and possible editing certain properties could mark it as needing adding/updating in the sitemap.

Assuming i will have millions of profiles added/being edited how can i manage this in a sensible manner.

i know i need a script that can append urls as each profile is created
i know the script will prob be a TASK - running at a set freq - perhaps the profiles have a property like "indexed" and the TASK sets them to "true" when the profiles are added to the map.
I dont see the best way to store the map - do i store it in the datastore i.e;

model=sitemaps

properties

key_name=sitemap_xml_1 (and for my map sitemap_index_xml)

mapxml=blobstore (the raw xml map or ror map)

full=boolean (set true when url count is 50) # might need this as a shard will tell us

To make this work my thoughts are

m cache the current site map structure as "sitemap_xml"
keep a shard of url count
when my task executes
1. build the xml structure for say the first 100 urls marked "index==false" (how many could u run at a time?)
2. test if the current mcache sitemap is full (shardcounter+100>50K)
3.a if the map is near full create a new map entry in models "sitemap_xml_2" - update the map_index file (also stored in my model as "sitemap_index" start a new shard - or reset.2
3.b if the map is not full grab it from mcache
4.append the 100 url xml structure
5.save / m cache the map

I can now add a handler using a url map/route like /sitemaps/*

Get my * as map name and serve the maps from the blobstore/mache on the fly.

Now my question is does this work - is this the right way or a good way to start? Will this handle the situation of making sure the search bots update when a user changes their profile - possibly by setting the change freq correctly? - Do i need a more advance system :( ? or have i re-invented the wheel!

I hope this is all clear and make some form of sense :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update frequency

Cache invalidation is a hard problem, see: [Cache Invalidation - Is there a General Solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188587/cache-invalidation-is-there-a-general-solution)

As far as I can see, you need to decide how often you *want* search bots to recrawl your site, rather than how often things are actually changed; if a user's page may contain information they want to remove at short notice, then you want the search bot to re-crawl within a couple of days, even though profiles are changed rarely on average.

#### Keeping an up-to-date map

Since the speed of your website now figures in its Google PageRank, it's worth updating a static file ready to serve up to the spiders. Perhaps have one script that continually updates a db table with sitemap entries, and another that periodically regenerates the static file(s) from the db table. That way, there is always a static version available for the spiders and it can all happen asynchronously.

#### Static pages on App Engine

I forgot that you can't have static page files on App Engine. According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930956/google-app-engine-caching-generated-html), the best way is to use generate your file and push it to memcache. Also see the documentation on [using memcache with App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache.html)

Comment: Am i correct in saying that on app engine the only way to serve a so-called "static file" that is dynamically constructed from a db file - is to store the dynamic page in a db and simply serve that content via a handler - On app engine it is not possible to create and save a static file?

Comment: @spidee GAE doesn't give you file access so you can store the file content either in database (datastore/blob) and/or serve it directly from memory/RAM through memcache .

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is very similar to how Django implements a sitemap framework: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/ specifically the section on creating index files: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index

If you want to see it on AppEngine with a patched version of the helper you can look here: http://code.google.com/p/dherbst-app-engine-django/wiki/Sitemaps

These are the changes applied to the helper: http://code.google.com/p/dherbst-app-engine-django/source/detail?r=509403105ec97fb1f3dfeadfada808f2cf1ff9a7